# npm installs dependencies with complete readme in a package.json -- invalid json results

Tags: node.js, npm

Today I upgraded npm and node.  I'm at 1.4.9 and 0.10.28, respectively.  (OSX 10.9.2.)

Since then, it seems that npm install is **writing "bad" package.json files for all of my dependencies**.

Specifically, it is **putting sevaral fields into the files that do not seem to be present in the source repo**'s package.json.

Like this example.  I have about 40 dev dependencies and they all have this junk (not to pick on gulp, I just happened to grab it for this example):

```
"readme": "<p align=\"center\">\n  <a href=\"http...",
"readmeFilename": "README.md",
"bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues"
},
"_id": "gulp@3.6.2",
"_shasum": "ea6b33d768db4a22294fa6339afb61842f5e6fb5",
"_from": "gulp@~3.6.2",
"_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp/-/gulp-3.6.2.tgz"
```

These are on the root of the package.json object.  Note, I've abbreviated the readme -- it's an entire html-ized version of the readme, and **in many of the files it's not properly escaped and thus makes package.json invalid and unusable**.

Obviously this leaves me dead in the water.  My questions are "what did I do"? And how do I undo it?  Did I wind up with a version of NPM that I shouldn't have? Could there be something else about my project, my node install, or the rest of my environment that might cause this?  I do have nave and a version of node in the 0.11 family, but that's not active and hasn't been in recent history -- could npm update -g npm have discovered that I have 0.11 in a different directory and jumped me into territory to which I should not have gone?  If so, how to I go backward?  I've tried npm installing npm back down into earlier versions but npm still reports the higher version number as if my install didn't happen, and I can't quite figure out what version I'm supposed to have, anyway.

What I've tried so far -- reinstalling node and npm, wiping out my node_modules for the project, and npm cache clean.  Nothing seems to have any effect. I'd be happy to answer any questions that I can about my environment that might help me resolve this.

TIA!

Comment: (actually when I mention doing something to my project, I've ruled that out by trying on a clean npm init-ed directory -- same result... the first dependency I install has this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just poked my way somewhat blindly into a solution.

*(although I suspect it didn't matter, I upgraded to the `master` branch code of npm)*

I believe that I fixed this by experimenting with setting `long = false` in my `.npmrc` file.  No more readmes in package.json files! :)

Aside: the package.json content that I see is quite foreign to me in its arrangement, but I guess that may be a function of being on a newer version.

At the very least, the package.json is now valid json and life is better again.  I'm not going to accept this, my own answer, just yet because I hope someone might be able to tell me *why* I needed to do this. This is an *override* in my .npmrc file as far as I understand it, so it seems bizarre that out of the blue I needed to add this override by hand based on no documentation....

I'll accept an answer that points me to an explanation of what happened or of what might have happened, if there is such an answer!  If none are forthcoming, I'll just accept my own answer so that the SO question loop is closed. Thanks!